# How I can convert an image from gallery or camera to binary string?

Tags: flutter, dart

I used image_picker to choose an image from gallery or take a photo with camera and now I have to send it on request to backend as an array of bytes. My issue is that I don't know How I can encode the image. Can anyone tell me what I should use and how?

Answer (score -1):

```
 var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

  File imageFile=image ;

  List<int> imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();

  String base64Image = base64UrlEncode(imageBytes);
```

Comment: I need to convert in base2 (binary) not in base64, but your method works. :)